# Return carriage back to 0,0 in Python 2.6

Tags: python, grid

Im trying to display a grid with moving individuals within it. At the moment im using a "clear screen" then display the grid. This is messy as the screen "flickers" every time.

In C and VB.NET there was methods of forcing the carriage to go back to the start of the console and overwrite content. This removed the flicker.

Is it possible in Python to do this? I've Googled around, and i found Curses, but thats Unix only (and i'll be working primarily within Windows).

Current Grid code (super basic):

```
#Clear() is a OS indepedent method of clearing the screen defined in code above, in windows its just os.system('cls')
clear()
x=0
y=0
tiles=""
tile=""
# Generate grid
while(y<max_y):
    while(x<max_x):
        tile = tileGen(x,y)
        tiles += str(tile)
        x+=1
    tiles += "\n"
    y+=1
    x=0
print(tiles)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help: [ANSI Escape Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

The Home command would be `'\x1b[0;0H'`.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work correctly (or im not implementing it correctly). I tried using sys.stderr.write("\x1b[0;0H"), but it just outputs gibberish (instead of moving the cursor). I also tried some of the other commands listed on that page, including "\x1b[u" and "\x1b[s"

Comment: If your terminal is ANSI (the DOS prompt, I.e. cmd.exe is), it should work, so you must be using something else and need to explain what.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, a python package does exist that wraps PDCurses, a windows-compatible curses library. The package, [`UniCurses`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/pyunicurses/), provides a uniform interface to either PDCurses (under windows) or python's native `curses` module, and so can be used to write cross-platform curses apps. It may be that [Mike Desimone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552343/577088)'s answer is enough for your needs though.